# How to change query tool font and colors in PgAdmin 4?

Tags: configuration, pgadmin-4

In PgAdmin III, it is possible to change the font and colors for the query tool editor window in the options menu:
[image]

I can't find any similar settings in the preferences window for PgAdmin 4. How and where can I change the font and colors?

Answer (score 0):

pgAdmin4 is different (python, react, etc.) to pgadmin3 ...
so you do your job in scss --> /web/pgadmin/static/scss/resources

look at this: https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/blob/master/README.md#creating-pgadmin-themes